# ¿Como hacer un AUTOUPDATE para actualizar sin PlayStore en Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, apk, descarga

alguno de ustedes sabe como se puede realizar la actualización de una aplicación que no se subira a la Play Store?

He pensado en que al momento de iniciar la aplicación este verificara su numero de versión interna (Versióncode y VersionName)y la comparara con un WebService y arrojara la descarga de la nueva apk, pero lo que no se realmente es, como poder hacer esto, se que se puede pero no se el código.

De antemano gracias, y espero que a alguno también le sirva.

Comment: creo que [este enlace](http://androcode.es/2012/03/aplicacion-auto-actualizable-sin-market/) te puede ayudar :)

Comment: Gracias, he logrado descifrar la interacción con este tutorial la verdad estuvo algo complicado de relacionar mas que nada, subire una actualización porque esa ya es una versión viejita.

Answer (score 1):

> He pensado en que al momento de iniciar la aplicación este verificara
>   su numero de versión interna (Versióncode y VersionName) y la comparara con un WebService

En realidad es correcto lo que propones, incluso no es necesario un Web Service, al iniciar tu  aplicación puede obtener el `versionCode` o `versionName` de la aplicación:

```
PackageInfo pinfo = null;
try {
    pinfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0);
} catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
int versionCode = pinfo.versionCode;
String versionName = pinfo.versionName;
```

y compararlo con el definido en un archivo de configuración que descargues al iniciar tu aplicación:

```
 {"versiones": {
      "version": [
        {
        "text": "Descarga la última versión en la Play Store.",
        "numVersion": "1.2",
        "update": "http://www.mydomain.com/application.apk"
        },
        {
        "text": "Descarga la última versión en la Play Store.",
        "numVersion": "1.2.1",
        "update": "http://www.mydomain.com/application.apk"
        }
      ] 
    }
}
```

Si la versión coincide puede iniciar la descarga del .apk a actualizar que también puedes definir en tu archivo de configuración, e incluso mostrar un mensaje.

Recuerda que en este caso que la instalación no proviene de Google Playstore, el usuario tendrá que ejecutar el .apk de manera manual.